# Advice needed for making a search box

Tags: android, database

I am working on an android application. My application includes
an activity which has two edit text fields. The first edit text field
stores the title the user enters and the next edit text field stores
the story or the data the user enters regarding to the title the user
just entered. The entries are  getting saved in a database table.

I was trying to make a search box, which could find the entries entered.
I read the following page for the search box
http://android-helper.blogspot.in/2011/03/android-search-in-listview-example.html
, but here they have initially taken all the list items to be stored in a string array.

I want to get the title fields from the database and when the user enters a
particular word in the search box , only those titles should be
displayed which have that particular word(s) entered.

Here is some part of the code of my main activity , that is the diary activity.

```
    public class DiaryActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        OnItemClickListener {

    public static final String ROW_ID = "row_id";
    static long row_passed;
    ImageButton add;
    ListView list;
    public static int position_item;
    static long id_item_clicked;
    SimpleCursorAdapter myAdapter;
    DataHolder myDataHolder; // <-- database class
    EditText Text;
    static String title = "";
    static String story = "";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initialiseVariables();
        registerForContextMenu(list);

        add.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void initialiseVariables() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        add = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
        try {
            myDataHolder = new DataHolder(DiaryActivity.this);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            myDataHolder.open();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            String error = e.toString();
            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            d.setTitle("Error");
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(error);
            d.setContentView(tv);
            d.show();

        } finally {
            Cursor c = myDataHolder.getAll();
            c.moveToFirst();
            // Log.d("Message", c.getString(1));
            myAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(DiaryActivity.this,
                    R.layout.mystoryholder, c, new String[] {
 // get the date from the system
                    DataHolder.KEY_TITLE, DataHolder.KEY_DAY,
                            DataHolder.KEY_MONTH, DataHolder.KEY_YEAR },
                    new int[] { R.id.titleTag, R.id.tvDate, R.id.tvMonth,
                            R.id.tvYear });
            list.setAdapter(myAdapter);

            list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            myDataHolder.close();
        }

    }
```

How can I get all the entries in the title_fields from the database, and convert them into individual strings and put them in a string array ,because once the entries in title_fields can be covered to a string array, only then can the above page example be used for further coding.

Comment: @Lucifier could you help me with this.